# Match multiple element's classes using RegExp

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I assign classes to my target elements, in my jquery plugin, like `plugin-prop-value`. So elements could have several of the type. Currently i just `attr('class').split(' ')` then `for` etc. Now I'm trying to access them using regexp directly.

I'm using this pattern `/\bplugin-(prop1|prop2|prop3)-(\S+)/g`.

`match()` gets me array of matching classes so i have to loop them again. ( loop->regexp, or loop->split )

`exec()` gets me only an array of first match `[ wholeclass, prop, value ]`, seems `g` flag doesn't play here but i was hoping for something more like

`[ [ wholeclass, prop, value ], [ ... ], [ ... ] ]`

What is the best approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a regex on a string to match multiple times, you just have to run `exec` again:

```
str = "prop-a prop-b prop-c";
re = /\bprop-([abc])/g;
while ((matches = re.exec(str))) {
    console.log(matches[1]);
}

// output is:
// a
// b
// c
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var pluginNameValuePairs= $.map(element.className.split(/\s+/), function(cls) {
    var parts= cls.split('-');
    if (parts.length<3 || parts[0]!=='plugin') return null;
    return [parts[1], parts.slice(2).join('-')];
});
```

If you need to put arbitrary characters in a value, such as whitespace or `-`, you might want to URL-encode them too.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has a [hasClass()](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) method which, in so far as I'm aware, caches the class names -- thus avoiding that they need to be parsed again and again.